# Centos 7 #openssl passwd - no sha512 option

Tags: openssl, centos7

My Centos7 machine employs hashing algorithm sha512 for passwords in /etc/shadow file.
But in the command line no output displayed when the following command is executed:

```
# openssl passwd -6 -salt xxx yyy     -- where xxx is the salt and yyy is the clear text password
```

to verify the options available for openssl passwd, i type:

```
# openssl passwd -6 -stdin
  Usage: passwd [options] [passwords]
  where options are
  -crypt             standard Unix password algorithm (default)
  -1                 MD5-based password algorithm
  -apr1              MD5-based password algorithm, Apache variant
  -salt string       use provided salt
  ... output omitted ...
```

Is it a standard behavior not having sha512 as an option for this command? 
Is there another command to generate sha512(salt+password) on the fly?

Comment: You should check the version of your openssl. The SHA256 and SHA512 options are available since [4e57a12](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/4e57a12ba73fd96254ffde00066e212c3219583e) which is around in the code base since 2016.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 ships an older version of OpenSSL, specifically a patched 1.0.2k. This version however does not provide the feature you're looking for.

Consider to use the meanwhile available `openssl11` RPM package from EPEL 7 which provides the same version of OpenSSL like RHEL/CentOS 8 has. Re-running your command with `openssl11` rather `openssl` leads to the desired result, then.